# Checking return with WP Error

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-error

I've seen other people with similar problems, and I know that I need to check the return when calling for the child items in my custom taxonomy "hhie_artists". I'm not sure how to `echo` my output to incorporate `wp_error`.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$taxonomyName = "hhie_artists";
//Call top layer terms only (by setting Parent to 0).
$parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => true));   
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
//Get the Child terms
$terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => true));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';  
}
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

From what I've found out, this is due to an empty taxonomy field being found. I've yet to populate all my custom taxonomy fields, so I'm not surprised by this error, I just need to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, but if I understand correctly you want to perform some testing on the return value in order to avoid iterating a `WP_Error` object and perhaps handle errors in some way.

According to the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Return_Values) `get_terms()` will return an array of term objects or `false` if no objects were found, but clearly by looking at the source it will return a WP_Error object if the taxonomy does not exists or in some cases an empty array.

Thus, to check for errors you will have to check if the return value matches `false`, empty array (`array()`) or a `WP_Error` object. Calling `empty($terms)` will account for the first two, and `is_wp_error($terms)` can be used for testing if the return value is an error object. Something like this will work for performing such testing:

```
$taxonomyName = "hhie_artists";
//Call top layer terms only (by setting Parent to 0).
$parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => true));   

if (!empty($parent_terms) && !is_wp_error($parent_terms)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
        //Get the Child terms
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => true));
        if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';  
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

However, there is already a function available in WordPress for printing a category tree like this. It's called [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) and i strongly suggest you use that instead. Here's how:

```
wp_list_categories(array(
    'title_li' => null, // We don't need the automatically generated heading
    'depth' => 1, // Judging from your code you only want to print one level of terms
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'taxonomy' => 'hhie_artists',
));
```

The result should follow this structure:

- Parent artist A

  - Child artist A1
  - Child artist A2
  - Child artist A3
- Parent artist B

  - Child artist B1
  - Child artist B2

Comment: Hi Simon, appreciate your answer. I had previously tried `wp_list_categories` but I'm having a few issues. The code above was originally intended to display "All Albums" on an Archives page. Albums are essentially children of my custom taxonomy "Artists". On the same page, I used a separate call to `wp_list_categories` to call only the parents to create an "All Artists" list.

Comment: Sorry, ran out of time editing: I should have explained that I am using the code an an "All Archives" page, and I wanted to call a list of all the parent terms in my custom taxonomy "Artists", to display "All Artists". I then want to display "All Albums", where Albums are the children of custom taxonomy "Artists". I realise this defers from my original question, but that was what the code was intended to do until I ran into `wp_error`. Can you help? I can't get `wp_list_categories`to work correctly with my custom taxonomy, showing only parent terms in a list, and then another of child terms.

Comment: I still don't see how the `wp_list_categories` example I posted above (I modified it to include your custom taxonomy) would generate anything other than what you are trying to achieve - have a look at the structural example output. But if it still does not work, checking the return value for `WP_Error` objects as in the first example should help you work around any errors. And if the issue is understanding *why* you get an error - try doing `if (is_wp_error($terms)) var_dump($terms)` or something. It should contain an explanation of the error, that's basically what its for.

Comment: I've now succeeded using your provided code. I'm not sure what went wrong when I tried earlier. Thanks a lot.